# video/gif lag on all browsers and media players since 18/04 upgrade

Tags: video, 18.04, budgie, gif

The other week I installed 18.04 Budgie on my Lenovo T430 and have been experiencing significant video (but not audio) lag between Opera, Chrome, Chromium, and VLC for embedded videos as well as .GIFs. If I keep flailing my mouse over the video it reduces the freezing but it doesn't stop it. Not experiencing this problem on my desktop or smart TV computer that I installed with the same USB image.

Edit:

lspci outputs the following:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Host Controller (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:16.3 Serial controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family KT Controller (rev 04)
00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev c4)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev c4)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev c4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation QM77 Express Chipset LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 04)
02:00.0 System peripheral: Ricoh Co Ltd MMC/SD Host Controller (rev 07)
03:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6205 [Taylor Peak] (rev 34)
```

and hwinfo --gfxcard spits out:

```
13: PCI 02.0: 0300 VGA compatible controller (VGA)              
  [Created at pci.378]
  Unique ID: _Znp.QL+9u+IjOc2
  SysFS ID: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0
  SysFS BusID: 0000:00:02.0
  Hardware Class: graphics card
  Model: "Intel 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller"
  Vendor: pci 0x8086 "Intel Corporation"
  Device: pci 0x0166 "3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller"
  SubVendor: pci 0x17aa "Lenovo"
  SubDevice: pci 0x21f3 
  Revision: 0x09
  Driver: "i915"
  Driver Modules: "i915"
  Memory Range: 0xf0000000-0xf03fffff (rw,non-prefetchable)
  Memory Range: 0xe0000000-0xefffffff (ro,non-prefetchable)
  I/O Ports: 0x5000-0x503f (rw)
  Memory Range: 0x000c0000-0x000dffff (rw,non-prefetchable,disabled)
  IRQ: 29 (226273 events)
  I/O Port: 0x00 (rw)
  Module Alias: "pci:v00008086d00000166sv000017AAsd000021F3bc03sc00i00"
  Driver Info #0:
    Driver Status: i915 is active
    Driver Activation Cmd: "modprobe i915"
  Config Status: cfg=new, avail=yes, need=no, active=unknown
Primary display adapter: #13
```

Comment: Hi Dan. Welcome to AskUbuntu! Can you please provide more information on the hardware you're using? Specifically the output of lspci and graphics details from hwinfo?

Comment: I added the outputs for lspci and hwinfo in the edits above, @tudor. Sorry if the formatting isn't quite right.

Comment: Thanks.  And have you installed `ubuntu-restricted-addons`?

Comment: I have installed the restricted addons. The rest of the addons seem to be working fine.